# Copy Excel row of information being pulled from a tab into a second row, but only changing the tab it's being pulled from

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy

I currently have an Excel row on a Summary Tab that is pulling information from a separate tab. (="Hood 1'!G12) is an example of one of the cells. Since there are over 800 cells in the row, I'm looking at copying the entire row exactly how it is, except replacing the tab it's being pulled from, and pasting it in the row below. So that particular cell above would now be (="Hood 2'!G12) in the row below.

The reason for this is each new tab is data collected for an automotive Hood. The report on each Hood is identical so every cell of data is in the same exact location for every report. Each report is on a separate tab. I want to copy and paste because the row has over 800 points of information.

Comment: What is your question? Copying info in Excel is pretty simple, so I'm assuming there's some other factor to your question, but I didn't see any other details to the request. Are you trying to do this repeatedly on multiple sheets, or repeatedly in the same sheet? Are you looking for VBA ("macro") code to do this? Please note two things: You need to clearly write a specific question in the body of your question post, and this is not a script writing service: we expect you to try things yourself and then bring the code you've got so far along with your question if you are asking for code/VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `INDIRECT` function. Enter this formula to the first cell and copy down:

```
=INDIRECT("'Hood " & ROW(A1) & "'!G12")
```